# Why can't I delete the document.body property?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

```
> delete document
  false
```

This I kind of understand: document is a non-configurable property of window.

```
> delete document.body
  true
> document.body
  <body>
  ...</body>
```

But what witchcraft is this?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I assume you'd have to use DOM methods, ie `document.documentElement.removeChild(document.body)`

Comment: Really looking forward to hearing a valid use case for ever needing to do this. Sounds like an XY problem. If this is just a bad science experiment it really doesn't matter why

Comment: The *document* and *body* objects are host objects and can pretty much do whatever they like. The W3C HTML specification says [*"on getting, must return the body element of the document"*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#dom-document-body). If you delete it, it can't do that.

Comment: @Phil—that will remove the body element from the document, but it won't remove the property.

Comment: @RobG I assumed that was what OP was attempting to do (but not enough to make it an answer)

Comment: in nonstrict, deleting a non-configurable property returns true without taking effect.

Comment: @Pointy Nothing, really. I was just curiously playing around with document and whatnot after noticing that HTMLElement objects are displayed differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because document doesn't have a "body" property. Or rather it doesn't have its OWN property.

```js
console.log(document.hasOwnProperty("body")); //false
//now let's mimic what we're seeing with document.body
function X(){
    
}

X.prototype.body = "Abc";

var foo = new X();

console.log(foo.body); //Abc
delete foo.body; //no effect because I don't have this property. My prototype does

console.log(foo.body); //Abc (still)

delete foo.__proto__.body; //delete the prototype's property

console.log(foo.body); //undefined (now)

delete document.__proto__.__proto__.body; //delete the doc
console.log(document.body); //undefined (now)
```

Comment: Afaik whether `body` is an own property or not depends a lot on the implementation. But good observation!

Comment: Yeah, and the prototype chain differs for Chrome (two levels up) versus Firefox (only one)

Comment: The W3C DOM Core specification only requires that the *body* attribute of the *document* object must return the document's body element, or null. It does not specify or imply how the attribute is implemented. The spec differentiates between undefined and null, so if implementations return undefined they are not compliant. Inheriting the *body* property doesn't seem like a good idea, if there are two instances of *document* in the same execution context, do they both inherit the same *body*?